# Inertias of the drivetrain components of a 4x4 vehicle or any geared system for that matter

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations, moment-of-inertia

I’m making a vehicle simulator and I’m not entirely sure if my inertia calculations are right or are completely wrong. What I currently have now is something like this:

**1. Engine:**

- **engine_Out_Inertia = engine_Inertia**; *this should contain the inertia of the engine and all of it’s auxiliaries, the flywheel and the clutch parts connected to it*

**2. Clutch:**

- **clutch_In_Inertia = engine_Out_Inertia**

when clutch disengaged:

- **clutch_Out_Inertia = clutch_Inertia**; *the clutch plate rotates with the gearbox, I guess it also could be included in transmission_Inertia, then this would be 0*

when clutch locked:

- **clutch_Out_Inertia = clutch_In_Inertia + clutch_Inertia**

when clutch is slipping:

- **clutch_Out_Inertia = clutch_In_Inertia * clucthLocking +
  clutch_Inertia**; *where clucthLocking is a 0-1 value where 0 is clutch is disengaged and 1 is locked? Or should I transfer all of the engine_Inertia once the clutch is engaged??*

**3. Transmission:**

- **tranmsmission_In_Inertia = clucth_Out_Inertia**
- **transmission_Out_Inertia = (tranmsmission_In_Inertia + transmission_Inertia) * gearRatio^2**

**4. Transfercase:**

- **transfercase_In_Inertia = transmission_Out_Inertia**

if 2WD, assuming the rear wheels are driven:

- **transfercase_Out_Inertia_FrontAxle = transfercaseFront_Inertia** *; front axle is disconnected, so only the inertia of the front driveshaft has to be taken into account?*
- **transfercase_Out_Inertia_ RearAxle = (transfercase_In_Inertia +
  transfercaseRear_Inertia) * gearRatio^2**

this is where it gets really confusing:

if 4WD:

- **transfercase_Out_Inertia_FrontAxle = (transfercase_In_Inertia +
  transfercaseFront_Inertia) * gearRatio^2**
- **transfercase_Out_Inertia_ RearAxle = (transfercase_In_Inertia +
  transfercaseRear_Inertia) * gearRatio^2**

*Should I divide the transfercase input inertia into two, given that the transfercase splits the torque 50/50?
In the case of rear axle inertia should I also add the inertia of the front axle components, given that the whole drivetrain is locked together? Something like this?*

- **transfercase_Out_Inertia_RearAxle = (transfercase_In_Inertia + transfercaseRear_Inertia + FrontRight_Wheel_Inertia + FrontLeft_Wheel_Inertia) * gearRatio^2**

*If this is the case, then full time 4WD cars that have a center differential should also behave like this? or only when the center differential is locked?*

**5. Differential:**

*Like in the case of the tranfercase, do I split the input inertia based on the left/right torque distribution in the differential? Do I include the left wheel side inertia in the right wheel side inertia calculation?*

- **Rear_Differential_In_Inertia = transfercase_Out_Inertia_RearAxle**
- **Rear_Differential_Out_Inertia_Left = (Rear_Differential_In_Inertia +
  differential_inertia) * finalDrive^2**
- **Rear_Differential_Out_Inertia_Right = (Rear_Differential_In_Inertia +
  differential_inertia) * finalDrive^2**

**6. Axle:**

- **Rear_Axle_Out_Inertia_LeftWheel = (Rear_Differential_Out_Inertia_Left + halfshaftLeft_Inertia)**
- **Rear_Axle_Out_Inertia_RightWheel = (Rear_Differential_Out_Inertia_Right + halfshaftRight_Inertia)**

*Sometimes you have unequal length halfshafts, part of the reason why cars torque steer?*

**7. Wheel:**

- **Right_Wheel_Inertia = Rear_Axle_Out_Inertia_RightWheel +
  wheelAssembly_Inertia + brakeDisc_Inertia**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can use this drivetrain model for the simulation with these equations

**kinematic**

$$ \omega_5=\frac{i_H}{2}\left(\omega_3+\omega_4\right)$$
$$\omega_7=\frac{i_V}{2}\left(\omega_1+\omega_2\right)$$
$$\omega_6=i_G\omega_5$$

thus, you obtain 4 generalized coordinates $~\omega_{1..4}~$ ($~\omega_{1..7}~$ minus
three constraint equations)

from here the Inertia matrix $~\mathbf I~$

$$\mathbf I=\mathbf J^T\,\mathbf \Theta\,\mathbf J$$

where

$$\mathbf J= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&0\\  0&1&0&0
\\  0&0&1&0\\  0&0&0&1
\\  0&0&1/2\,i_{{G}}i_{{H}}&1/2\,i_{{G}}i_{{H}}
\\  0&0&1/2\,i_{{H}}&1/2\,i_{{H}}
\\  1/2\,i_{{V}}&1/2\,i_{{V}}&0&0\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

$$\mathbf \Theta=\rm diag\left(\Theta_i\right)\quad, i=1..7$$

$$\mathbf I=
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} \Theta_{{1}}+1/4\,{i_{{V}}}^{2}\Theta_{{7
}}&1/4\,{i_{{V}}}^{2}\Theta_{{7}}&0&0\\  1/4\,{i_{{V}
}}^{2}\Theta_{{7}}&\Theta_{{2}}+1/4\,{i_{{V}}}^{2}\Theta_{{7}}&0&0
\\  0&0&\Theta_{{3}}+1/4\,{i_{{G}}}^{2}{i_{{H}}}^{2}
\Theta_{{5}}+1/4\,{i_{{H}}}^{2}\Theta_{{6}}&1/4\,{i_{{G}}}^{2}{i_{{H}}
}^{2}\Theta_{{5}}+1/4\,{i_{{H}}}^{2}\Theta_{{6}}\\  0
&0&1/4\,{i_{{G}}}^{2}{i_{{H}}}^{2}\Theta_{{5}}+1/4\,{i_{{H}}}^{2}
\Theta_{{6}}&\Theta_{{4}}+1/4\,{i_{{G}}}^{2}{i_{{H}}}^{2}\Theta_{{5}}+
1/4\,{i_{{H}}}^{2}\Theta_{{6}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

---

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I’m not sure how this diagram is supposed to help me, because I already have this setup, even a better one, because you are missing the transfer case. The torque flow in the system is working as it should. I have problem with calculating the inertias as stated in the title and I don’t understand how this is supposed to help me. Could you perhaps give a more in depth explanation?

Comment: I will write you the equations for the Inertia